# класс System, обращение к методу через static переменную (концепция)

Tags: java

По стандарту во все программы на [java](/questions/tagged/java) импортируется пакет `java.lang`, в котором содержится класс `System` реализующий обращение с потоками через `public final static` переменные `in` и `out`. При этом в классе также определены `static` методы `print()` и `println()`. Объясните пожалуйста, каким образом через точечную нотацию, при обращении к классу и его переменной вообще возможно вызывать метод. `System.out.print();`

Сильно камнями не бейте, я только недавно начал изучать Java по Г.Шилдту, сейчас на 10 главе (потоки). Возможно что-то подзабыл.

Comment: Я что-то не понимаю. Есть класс `Сlass One{ int x;
 One(int x){this.x = x;} }`
Ну и вызывайте себе на здоровье из любого места: 
`One one = new One(1);
System.out.println(one.x);`

Comment: Дело в том что там static final переменные, для которых не нужно создавать объект для обращения и память для них выделяется не димамически. Кроме того это еще и константы, так как объявлены как final. Я не понимаю что в этих переменных записано и какого они типа?

Comment: Java - это открытый язык, можно полезть в любой класс и руками посмотреть что где записано и как что выполняется.

Comment: Так приложите кусок кода, со словами "сделать я хочу вот это". А то очень не ясно, что вы хотите.  _каким образом через точечную нотацию, при обращении к классу и его переменной вообще возможно вызывать метод_ получается вам нужно просто распечатать на экране переменную класса? Или другие проблемы?

Comment: Я просто хочу понять концепцию, начинку, содержание...

Answer (score 3):

Константа **out** является экземпляром класса `PrintStream`, у которого и определяется метод `println()` и тд.

Константа **in** является экземпляром класса `InputStream`, который определяет `read ()`, `skip ()`, `avalible ()`, `mark ()`, `reset ()`, `marSkupported ()`.

Получается, когда вы используете `System.out.println("Hi, World")`, вы обращаетесь сначала к final экземпляру и вызываете у него статический метод `println ()`.

Comment: Спасибо, я допер. Поправьте пожалуйста если ошибаюсь, Константы out и in являются переменными ссылочного типа абстрактных классов PrintStream и InputStream(определены в final классе System) и не на что при этом не ссылаются. Таким образом, так как метод не переопределен, мы можем его вызвать.

Answer (score -2):

В общем, если кому нужно будет я нашел ответ на свой вопрос в том же Шилдте, там опечатка под редакцией для Java SE 8.

В классе `System` есть три static переменные ссылочного типа - **in**, **out**, **err**. Все три переменные являются константами и ссылаются на объекты классов `InputStream` и `PrintStream`, а так как в Шилдте указано, что класс `InputStream` является абстрактным, то для него нельзя вызвать конструктор. `{ FatalError(); }` 
Или очипятка и `InputStream` не абстрактный, или переменная **in** объявлена как ссылка типа InputStream и ей не присваивается ссылка на объект типа `InputStream`.